# Append a few word documents

Tags: c#

I am trying to find and replace text in word document and then combine all documents in one. So far I got the find and replace part working. How can i combine/append all documents in one. 
How can I stop the documents from opening after the text is replaced?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] documents = { @"C:\file1.docx",
                           @"C:\file2.docx",
                           @"C:\file3.docx"};

    foreach (string fileName in documents)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application { Visible = true };
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName, ReadOnly: false, Visible: true);
        //aDoc.Activate();
        FindAndReplace(wordApp, "{ Contractor_Name}", "John Doe");
        FindAndReplace(wordApp, "{day}", "1");
        FindAndReplace(wordApp, "{year}", "17");
        FindAndReplace(wordApp, "{month}", "August");
    }
}

private static void FindAndReplace(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application doc, object findText, object replaceWithText)
{
    //options
    object matchCase = false;
    object matchWholeWord = true;
    object matchWildCards = false;
    object matchSoundsLike = false;
    object matchAllWordForms = false;
    object forward = true;
    object format = false;
    object matchKashida = false;
    object matchDiacritics = false;
    object matchAlefHamza = false;
    object matchControl = false;
    object read_only = false;
    object visible = true;
    object replace = 2;
    object wrap = 1;
    //execute find and replace
    doc.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
        ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
        ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
}
```

Comment: The OP of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118530/merge-and-split-word-documents-using-microsoft-office-interop-word-in-c-sharp already has code to merge

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to add my document dynamical not from array. I am wandering if I should save them first in array with the changed text and then merge them.

Comment: Maybe, that's something I can't test for you, good luck.